# List all nullable django model fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model with both nullable and non-nullable fields. Let's consider an example:

```py
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.CharField(null=False)
    field_2 = models.CharField(null=True)
    field_3 = models.ForeignKey(SomeOtherModel, null=True)
    field_4 = models.ForeignKey(YetAntherModel, null=False)
```

How could I get list of nullable field names (as in example below) from MyModel class?

```py
['field_2', 'field_3']
```

Right now I have hardcoded mapping which I need to update together with model changes so I'd like to have some generic method for it.

Any idea would be appricieated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the fields, and filter the `null` paramete, like:

```
[f for f in MyModel._meta.get_fields() if f.null]
```

Or if you are only interested in the field *name* (not the field), then you can write:

```
[f.name for f in MyModel._meta.get_fields() if f.null]
```

For your given `MyModel`, this gives us the expected:

```
>>> [f.name for f in MyModel._meta.get_fields() if f.null]
['field_2', 'field_3']
```